# qt serial receiver missing data

Tags: c++, qt, microcontroller

I am trying to read my SerialPort based on the
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-creadersync-main-cpp.html
example:

```
QCoreApplication coreApplication(argc, argv);

QTextStream standardOutput(stdout);

QSerialPort serialPort;
QByteArray readData;

serialPort.setPortName("ttyS4");
serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::EvenParity);
serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serialPort.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

if (!serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    standardOutput << QObject::tr("Failed to open port") << endl;
    return 1;
}

while (serialPort.waitForReadyRead(5000))
    readData.append(serialPort.readAll());
qDebug() << readData;

return coreApplication.exec();
```

I also tried reading Data based on the http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-cwriterasync-example.html example:

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication coreApplication(argc, argv);

    QTextStream standardOutput(stdout);
    QSerialPort serialPort;


    serialPort.setPortName("ttyS4");
    serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::EvenParity);
    serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);


    if (!serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Failed to open port") << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SerialPortReader serialPortReader(&serialPort);

    return coreApplication.exec();
}
```

serialPortReader:

```
SerialPortReader::SerialPortReader(QSerialPort *serialPort, QObject *parent):QObject(parent), m_serialPort(serialPort), m_standardOutput(stdout)
{

    connect(m_serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(handleReadyRead()));
    connect(m_serialPort, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), SLOT(handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));
    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(handleTimeout()));
    m_counter = 0;
    m_timer.start(5000);
}

SerialPortReader::~SerialPortReader()
{
}

void SerialPortReader::handleReadyRead()
{   m_counter++;
    m_readData.append(m_serialPort->readAll());
    qDebug()<< m_serialPort->readAll();
    qDebug() << "triggered" << m_counter;
}

void SerialPortReader::handleTimeout()
{
    if (m_readData.isEmpty()) {
        m_standardOutput << QObject::tr("No data was currently available for reading from port %1").arg(m_serialPort->portName()) << endl;
    } else {
        m_standardOutput << QObject::tr("Data successfully received from port %1").arg(m_serialPort->portName()) << endl;
        m_standardOutput << m_readData << endl;
    }

    QCoreApplication::quit();
}

void SerialPortReader::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError serialPortError)
{
    if (serialPortError == QSerialPort::ReadError) {
        m_standardOutput << QObject::tr("An I/O error occurred while reading the data from port %1, error: %2").arg(m_serialPort->portName()).arg(m_serialPort->errorString()) << endl;
        QCoreApplication::exit(1);
    }
}
```

But when I send data to this COM port (with same serialPort Settings for Sender), not all of the data is received.

With the MSB-RS232 I can check which data really has been sendet to the port and there is nothing wrong with my sender.

For testing I am sending

main:

```
QString alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";
handler.writetoPort(alpha);
```

handler.cpp:

```
void SerialHandler::writetoPort(QString x)
{
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    QByteArray encodedVar = codec->fromUnicode(x);
    writetoPort(encodedVar);
}

void SerialHandler::writetoPort(const QByteArray x)
{
    serial.write(x);
    serial.waitForBytesWritten(-1);
}
```

The result of this is the output:
abyz123456789 or abcdklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789 or abcdefghijklm or ...

It's always different.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on here?

Thank you for reading my long post.

--added 17.07--

This might be mandatory for my problem:
The code has to run on a microprocessor.

- CPU: Atmel -AT91SAM9X25 - ARM926(ARMv5) - 400MHz
- RAM: 32 MB
- Linux Kernel Version: 3.9.0
- QT Version: 5.4.1 (cross compiled)

both the async and sync example are working perfectly fine on my Windows PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the exact same Projekt on a different Board and everything works smoothly.
I think the COM Port of the old Board might have been damaged.

Will mark this as resolved but I can't tell what the true problem really was.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
void SerialPortReader::handleReadyRead()
{   
    m_counter++;
    while (m_serialPort->bytesAvailable())
    {
        m_readData.append(m_serialPort->readAll());
    }
    qDebug()<< m_readData;
    qDebug() << "triggered" << m_counter;
}
```

Comment: 1ST RUN:
"q"
triggered 1
"qrstuv"
triggered 2
"qrstuvwxyz1234567"
triggered 3
"qrstuvwxyz123456789"
triggered 4
Data successfully received from port ttyS4
qrstuvwxyz123456789

2ND RUN:
"jk"
triggered 1
"jklmnop"
triggered 2
"jklmnopqrstuvwxyz1"
triggered 3
Data successfully received from port ttyS4
jklmnopqrstuvwxyz1

I had one run with all charackters but I did not change anything in the code between the runs...

Thanks for your answer, but this did not solve my problem